# How can I get p-values for Durbin-Watson statistic using prais_winsten function in R?

Tags: r, p-value, autocorrelation

I am trying to obtain p-values for the transformed Durbin-Watson Statistic.

Using `dwtest` to examine my time series data for AR(1) serial correlation yields the following:

```
dwtest(rate ~ x + y + z,
+       data = data)

Durbin-Watson test

data:  rate ~ time + consent + tsi
DW = 1.243, p-value = 0.003155
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

which is why I used the prais_winsten estimator.

```
prais <- prais_winsten(rate ~ x + y + z, 
                          data = data)
```

`summary(prais)` yields the following

```
...
Durbin-Watson statistic (original): 1.243 
Durbin-Watson statistic (transformed): 1.566
```

So I now have the D-W-statistic for my prais-winsten model, but no p-values. Is there any way to receive them using this method? Is it necessary to report the p-values when reporting the DW statistic?

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if this is what your looking for. The p-values are in the `summary` output. You can get them with: `summary(prais)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"]`

Cheers, Rico

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was not referring to the p-values of my coefficients, but to the p-value of the adjusted Durbin-Watson statistic. As you can see in my first chunk, the dwtest function yields a p-value for the DW statistic, which indicates wether the null-hypothesis of no AC should be rejected. When using prais_winsten, no p-value for the adjuest DW statistic is given and that's the p-value I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.